# Identity Server 4 cannot rediect to Angular 2 web site after authentication

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, identityserver4

I am trying to implement angular 2 client for Identity server 4. I can direct the authentication page to enter user id and password. After the information is entered, the Visual studio trace displayed the following info:

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 235.651ms 302
```

However, there was error when Identity server tried to return to angular 2 web site. The error message is

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id_token'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id_token'
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:4200/js/vendor.bundle.js:103810:16) [angular]
at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/js/vendor.bundle.js:103779:29) [angular]
at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/js/vendor.bundle.js:59700:31) [angular]
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: you need to catch the redirect with idtoken and handle the client signin. stop redirecting to the url if it is not a valid page. This is usually handled by server-side middleware (e.g. OpenID connect middleware)

Comment: What does your redirect URL look like? Are you using Routing?